# How to Combine Get-ADOrganizationalUnit with Get-ADUser

Tags: powershell

I need to combine this 4 commands in a txt or csv file with 2 columns 1 Column With OU's and another column with users from that OU's separate with a "," (coma).

Like:

```
OU1,user1

OU1,user2

OU2,user3

OU3,user4
```

I have for commands but I want to combine.

```
#List OUS RDS
$ou1=Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=RDS Funcional,DC=esofitec,DC=loc" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

##ista OUS VDI
$ou2=Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=VDI Funcional,DC=esofitec,DC=loc" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

$ou3=$ou1+$ou2

#List users without adm and test in RDS OU
$user1=Get-ADUser -Filter {(name -notLike "test*") -and (name -notlike "adm*")} -SearchBase "OU=RDS Funcional,DC=esofitec,DC=loc" | Select-Object Name

#List users without adm o test VDI OU
$user2=Get-ADUser -Filter {(name -notLike "test*") -and (name -notlike "adm*")} -SearchBase "OU=VDI Funcional,DC=esofitec,DC=loc" | Select-Object Name

$user3=$user1+$user2

$output=$ou3+$user3

$output | Out-File -FilePath c:\test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to join them all in one file you can greatly simplify your code while achieving your desired results. As you are wanting users joined by comma I changed the csv delimiter to a semicolon.

```
"OU=RDS Funcional,DC=esofitec,DC=loc","OU=VDI Funcional,DC=esofitec,DC=loc" | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -SearchBase $_ | ForEach-Object {
        $users = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -notlike 'test*' -and Name -notlike 'adm*'" -SearchBase $_.distinguishedname

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            OU    = $_.name
            Users = $users.name -join ', '
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path path\to\exportfile.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'
```

**Edit**

Regarding your comment, if you'd like to see the amount of users instead of the users names you can modify it slightly like this

```
"OU=RDS Funcional,DC=esofitec,DC=loc","OU=VDI Funcional,DC=esofitec,DC=loc" | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -SearchBase $_ | ForEach-Object {
        $users = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -notlike 'test*' -and Name -notlike 'adm*'" -SearchBase $_.distinguishedname

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            OU    = $_.name
            Users = "{0} users" -f $users.count
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path path\to\exportfile.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'
```

Comment: Hi

if i want to get numbers of each ou instead the name? How can i do?

For exemple:

OU1, 3 users

OU2, 4 users

OU3, 2 users

Thanks :)

Best!

Comment: A count of the users instead of the users names.